# babel es5 to es6 converting less extension to css on imports

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs, npm-scripts

I wrote some npm scripts that builds the `./lib` directory before publish to npm.
1. script is responsible to convert all `es6` `*.js` files in `./src/components/` to `es5` syntax and then copy the files to `./lib` (same structure).
This is the script:

```
"cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel ./src/components --out-dir ./lib --ignore spec.js --copy-files"
```

And this is the `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    "stage-1"
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": [
        "latest",
        "react-hmre"
      ]
    },
    "production": {
      "presets": [
        [
          "latest",
          "es2015"
        ]
      ],
      "plugins": [
        "transform-react-constant-elements",
        "transform-react-remove-prop-types",
        [
          "transform-imports",
          {
            "react-bootstrap": {
              "transform": "react-bootstrap/lib/${member}",
              "preventFullImport": true
            },
            "lodash": {
              "transform": "lodash/${member}",
              "preventFullImport": true
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    },
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        "latest"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have another script that responsible to convert `.less` files to `.css` and copy them to `./lib` (same structure):

```
"lessc-glob ./src/components/**/*.less lib"
```

Everything works well as expected, but i have one problem now. The `import` that i have inside the `.js` files are referring to `.less` files, but i need it to change to `.css` extensions.
To make things clear,
What i have now is:

```
import css from './styles.less';
```

Converted into this:

```
var _styles = require('./styles.less');
```

But i want it to convert to this:

```
var _styles = require('./styles.css');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace) can be installed and utilized to find instances of *.less* and replace them with *.css* in your resultant ES5 `.js` file/s.

**npm script**

Add a `replace` script to your `package.json` as follows:

```json
...
"scripts": {
  ...
  "replace": "replace \".less\" \".css\" ./lib/components/ -r --include=\"*.js\""
},
...
```

A call to the `replace` script can then be chained to the end your script that is responsible for converting all es6 `*.js` files. E.g.

```json
...
"scripts": {
  ...
  "quux": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel ./src/components --out-dir ./lib --ignore spec.js --copy-files && npm run replace",
  "replace": "replace \".less\" \".css\" ./lib/components/ -r --include=\"*.js\""
  ...
},
...
```

*Note the* `&& npm run replace` *part added to the end of your current `quux` script.*

I've assumed the `components` folder is copied to the `lib` folder too. If it's not then the `./lib/components/` part in the `replace` script will need to be changed to `./lib/`.

Comment: thank you, it seems like a nice solution and it works well with a little test i did. the great part of this solution is that i can use it programmatic as well  https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace#programmatic-usage